# First Come, First Served process scheduling

Tags: linux-kernel, unix, kernel

i have 4 processes:

```
p1 - bursts 5, priority: 3
p2 - bursts 8, priority: 2
p3 - bursts 12, priority: 2
p4 - bursts 6, priority: 1
```

Assuming that all processes arrive at the scheduler at the same time what is the average response time and average turnaround time? 
For FCFS is it ok to have them in the order p1, p2, p3, p4 in the execution queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The average response time and average turnaround time depends on the type of the scheduler (cooperative or preemptive). For the FCFS, yes it is ok to have them in the order p1, p2, p3, p4. This is a homework assignment...

See also:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29#Common_scheduling_practices